# What would humans look like if their blood were silver?

Tags: creature-design, humans, blood, unusual-color

I have a species in mind that I want to write about for a book I'm planning, and they look exactly like humans (minus the 'unnatural' hair and eye colors they can posses). However, they have silver blood, so what would their skin and such look like? Would it still have a pinkish/reddish tint, or would their skin be more pale? I wanted to go with paler skin, especially around places that have thinner skin (lips) but I'm not sure if that makes sense. I wanted some outside opinions.

Comment: Animals and humans share the same color blood, but have vast differences in appearances, so the color of blood can't be take as any indication of species appearance.

Comment: I was thinking their general features would look exactly the same, I just thought the color of silver blood would make the species look paler in comparison to red blooded humans. But yes, that does make sense now that I think of it like that.

Comment: By silver blood, do you mean blood that contains silver compounds, or silver-colored blood? Most answers seem to assume the former so far.

Answer (score 11):

Silver in the human body does interesting things to our appearance.

Most notably, it makes (particularly light skinned people) us look like this:

[image]

Ingesting colloidal silver (finely particulate silver suspended in water) will eventually turn your skin a metally-blue colour, a condition called [argyria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argyria).

The fluid in your people's blood that carries the silver within it may very well cause the same result.

Argyria shouldn't be confused with methemoglobinemia, which is a genetic trait found, for example, among the [Blue Fugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Fugates) and other families of the USA:

[image]

The skin colouration is similar, but in the latter case, it's the iron ion in the blood rather than silver that performs the change.

Answer (score 4):

If their blood were silver then they would glow red/orange tending to yellow.

Liquid silver exists between the temperature of 961.78 °C, ​1763.2 °F and 2162 °C, ​3924 °F,
their spectral emissions would be from the infra red all the way to daffodil, depending on how hot they are, as you can see on this chart (scale in Celsius):

[image]

<sup>Attribution Wikipedia 2019, CC license.</sup>

Their [black body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Blackbody_peak_wavelength_exitance_vs_temperature.svg) could make them dangerous to be near.
It strikes me that they'd be dangerous to be around because they radiate so much heat. It'd be the [torment of Tantalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalus) if you fell in love with one.

Comment: You've clearly gone with the viewpoint that "silver" meant the element rather than the *color*.   Not uninteresting, but probably something to check in comments before answering.

Comment: @StephenG comments are ephemeral and often deleted. Don't expect people to look at comments for clarifications.

Comment: @Renan You've totally misunderstood.  I'm saying he should have asked for clarification using a comment to ask (for an edit clarifying).

Comment: @StephenG In retrospect I think so too.

Comment: In fairness I (like most people) did not think of the other possible meanings and just latched onto whichever meaning each of us first assumed.  So it's not a criticism of you in particular.

Answer (score 1):

If your species blood was always silver, then I imagine the lips, cheeks, etc would take on a flat metallic look in combination with their skin tone -- so for Caucasoids that would mean not shiny but maybe like the dull side of tin foil. For darker skin tones it might look like the deep hue of bronze (a brownish metal before it oxidizes)

Our blood is red when it's oxygenated and bluish when its deoxygenated.  So think about amending your question to include the equivalent states if you want a more complex answer for your species.

Comment: The “blue blood when deoxygenated” rumor is actually a bit misleading - deoxygenated blood is a dark red/ruddy purple, not a vivid blue. Veins appear blue because the skin scatters light differently!

Comment: I actually wanted to make it so that their blood consistently stayed silver, whether it was inside or outside. I was heading down the path of their blood not oxidizing like humans, which would mean that nothing in their blood would react/bond to oxygen. Also thank you for your answer, it helped a lot.

Comment: @tyjo you have to take into account the chemistry of what the blood is doing for the body. Look at the different oxide states of silver and see what color they are. Also, human blood is not just iron, its hemoglobin, a chemical compound that carries oxygen well. you may need to find a chemical equivalent or change the creatures biology to fit it.